# Marketing Cloud Supported Font Formats

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have fonts with `.otf` and `.ttf` file format, but these are not supported by marketing cloud.

Where else can I store my fonts other than AWS and use it in my emails and landing pages?

Comment: how have you uploaded them? I'm pretty sure we used same font formats successfully, by uploading them to classic content and then pulling in the file in our html.

Comment: @KennethWagner were you able to upload those file formats into ET?, I don't see these file formats as supported by marketing cloud.

Comment: It's a while back but yeah, in e-mail studio's Classic content we could

Answer (score 1):

Contact Marketing Cloud Support to enable you to upload these file types.

Comment: Ooh, this is a good development.  I'm gonna get support on the horn and get this enabled in a few accounts.